# Can not access Netgear EX6200 through www.mywifiext.net

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, netgear-router, hsts

1. I try to configure a Netgear EX6200, as described on label and other instructions, including:
2. I connect to the wifi that the device provides.
3. I then access "http://www.mywifiext.net".
4. In Chrome, Chromium, Firefox or Edge quietly force a redirect to "https://www.mywifiext.net". (This is because [www.mywifiext.net](http://www.mywifiext.net) is included in "HSTS preload" list as indicated here: https://hstspreload.org/?domain=www.mywifiext.net )
5. The device does not support https, so the browser will fail to connect, and show any kind of "cannot connect to the server" message.

(The device is running the latest firmware, V1.0.3.94_1.1.128)

Comment: I am confused. In your question you say the domain is already in the HSTS preload, but your solution to your own question, is to use the already suggested domain by Netgear. Why have you submitted 3 partial answers to your own question?

Comment: Clarified that answer to show that it is ".com" instead of ".net" - the .com variant seems to be undocumented.
Each answer alone is enough to work around the issue, but have different pros/cons (and have varying likelihood of breaking in the future)

Answer (score 1):

Connect to http://www.mywifiext.com instead (note: ".com" instead of ".net").

This may not work forever, that domain may end up in HSTS preload list in the future.

Also, if you visit http://www.mywifiext.com without being connected through the device (and you get the "You are not connected to your extender's WiFi network." message - your browser is going to cache the domain as an HTTPS site, and it will stop working when you try to connect to it on your device (Firefox: Find it in history, right click and select "Forget about this site", Chrome: Go to chrome://net-internals/#hsts )

Overall this is a very unstable solution, but extremely convenient when it works.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disable the HSTS security feature.

This is not possible in current versions of Chrome, Chromium or Edge, but it IS possible in Firefox:

1. Downloand, install and run Firefox
2. Type in address bar: about:config
3. Select "Accept the risks"
4. Find "network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist"
5. Change "True" to "False".
6. Restart Firefox (may not be necessary)
7. Now you should be able to use Firefox to access http://www.mywifiext.net as intended. (If it doesn't work, double check so that you are not trying to go to "https://..."
8. Once you are done, recommend repeating the steps (set it back to True) to keep your system as secure as possible.

(Another similar solution is to find any other browser that does not implement HSTS or allows to disable it.)

Answer (score 0):

Use IP address to access the device.

Essentially, everytime you want to go to http://www.mywifiext.net, you instead type the IP address, e.g. "http://192.168.xx.xx" instead. Problem is, the IP address will vary depending on the extender's current configuration.

**If you bought the router used, or you replaced your main router, or it's for any other reason not properly configured to extend your current wifi:**

- Probably easiest to reset it to factory settings first: Plug in the power, wait for a few minutes, press the Reset button for a couple of seconds until lights starts flashing, then wait for a few more minutes.

**If the router is factory new, or you just reset it to factory settings:**

- Connect to the wifi "NETGEAR_EXT"
- The IP address is always "192.168.1.250", i.e., you go to "http://192.168.1.250".
- Note as as you follow the guide on screen, once you are told to connect to the new extended wifi, this address will stop working, continue below.

**If you have already configured the device:**

- The following steps SHOULD work regardless if you are connected to the main router/wifi or the extended wifi, but if it doesn't work, try connecting to the other.
- The following steps SHOULD also be the same regardless if you configured your Netgear device as wifi extender or AP.
- Log in to the administration interface of your router, as per label/instructions for that.
- Somewhere, there should be a list of "connected devices" or something like that, showing all computers, phones etc connected to the router. The Netgear device should be included in the list, and it's IP address (something like 192.168.xx.xx) should be displayed.
- Note that number and type the address http://192.168.xx.xx (using the correct number).
- Keep in mind that this address is not permanent, the router may assign a new IP address to the extender at any point (in particular if you restart the router) - if it stops working, just repeat these steps.